# Uninstall adobe reader

Tags: uninstall, adobe

When I try to remove adobe reader, it shows the following error:

```
jeeva@jeeva-HCL-ME-Laptop:~$ sudo apt-get remove adobe reader
[sudo] password for jeeva: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package adobe
E: Unable to locate package reader
jeeva@jeeva-HCL-ME-Laptop:~$ ''
```

Can you help me get rid out from this problem?

Comment: A package may not contain a space. When writing a space it's treated like two different packages

Answer (score 0):

There is no `adobe` or `reader` package.

The package is called `acroread`. But it is obsolete and not supported any more.